# Does Instaloader have a limit on the maximum number of followers/following usernames that can be downloaded?

Tags: python, csv, instagram, instagram-api, instaloader

I've been using Instaloader and noticed something peculiar when it comes to downloading usernames from followers or following. **Does Instaloader have any restrictions on the number of followers or following usernames it can fetch?**

I ask this because I was downloading the usernames of an account with over **100k followers**, and when I've reached username number 24K, **it abruptly stopped and proceeded to the next target username that I had set in my script**. To clarify, **I did not set any limitations in my script** to restrict downloading usernames only up to 24K.